# Is there a way to integrate PHP with Visual Studio 2017 for free?

Tags: php, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

The only option I discovered is to install an extension called PHP Tools for Visual Studio 2017 which costs $80

Answer (score 0):

I do not see any free php extensions for visual studio 2017. Could you use visual studio code it is free and supports php development?

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/nicktrog/2016/02/11/configuring-visual-studio-code-for-php-development/

Comment: Yes, I can use other IDEs, I just thought I'd give it a shot and ask anyway because I want to put all my development into one IDE.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of completeness, this is an extension written for VS 2013 that can be hacked to install into VS 2017 with some parts allegedly working while some others not:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SamHarwell.PHPLanguageSupport